# How to get the selected value and text from a dropdown on page load and on click a button with reactive form in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a dropdown whose data is coming from loop.Here I need to get the selected value and selected text on load and on click a span.I am using reactive form here.When I am using value, selected dropdown is coming empty on default selection. Here is the code below

### home.component.html

```
<div>
<form [formGroup]="registerForm">
<select formControlName="title" class="form-control">

                        <option *ngFor="let grpdata of group" value="{{grpdata.groupid}}">{{grpdata.groupname}}</option>

                    </select>
 </form>
</div>
<p>home works!</p>
<div><span (click)="getSelectedVal()">Click here</span></div>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonserviceService } from './../utilities/services/commonservice.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  getListData: any;
  registerForm: FormGroup;
  group:any;
  constructor(private commonserviceService: CommonserviceService,private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            title: ['', Validators.required]
     })
      this.group = [{"groupid":1,"groupname":"project1"},{"groupid":2,"groupname":"project2"},{"groupid":3,"groupname":"project3"}];
      console.log('selected value is')
      console.log('selected text is')
  }
 getSelectedVal(){
     console.log('selected value is on click is')
     console.log('selected text is on click is')
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getSelectedVal() {
   console.log("selected value is on click is", this.registerForm.get("title").value);
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-yq5kbx?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer,here some issue is there onload of page default selection is coming empty,  and I need to capture selected value and text both on load of page and also onclick

Comment: I have created a demo here everything is working fine since I hardcoded it with " title: new FormControl(1)" in app.component.ts file, but its not correct way if I remove first object of array from my json and reload the page its creating  error.How to write dynamically any idea? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lwrvvz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

UIappDeveloper, make it in two steps:

```
 getSelectedVal(){
   const value=this.registerForm.get('title').value; //get the value
   const status=this.statusdata.find(v=>v.groupid==value) //use "find"
                //status can be null, so I use ternary operator
                //else you are trying to get null.groupname and give you error
   console.log("value=",value,"status=",status?status.groupname:null)

 }
```